# Llamar datos sin valores en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Al momento tengo una consulta en MySQL que suma los consumo que una cierta persona hizo en un rango de tiempo:

```
SELECT e.codigo, round(sum(c.valor),2) as cupo FROM tbl_consumo c 
INNER JOIN tbl_empleado e 
    on c.tbl_empleado_id=e.id 
WHERE fecha like '%2018-12%' 
GROUP BY e.codigo;
```

Entonces las tablas tienen los siguientes datos:

**Tabla_personas:**

- Pepe
- Maria
- Gonzalo
- Paulina

**Tabla_consumos**

- 2018/12/18 1 Pepe
- 2018/12/01 1 Gonzalo
- 2018/11/18 1 Gonzalo
- 2018/12/20 1 Maria
- 2018/11/05 1 Pepe

El Resultado es el siguiente:

- Pepe 1
- Gonzalo 1
- Maria 1

Pero quiero que el resultado me muestre en cero al usuario sin consumos.

- Pepe 1
- Gonzalo 1
- Maria 1
- Paulina 0

Hay alguna manera de plantearlo

Comment: Me parece que en este caso debes plantear la consulta con LEFT JOIN, creo que con eso te puede dar los valores de una tabla que no hay en el inner Join.

Comment: Hace el from empleado y dsp left join con consumo y donde no haya consumo va a mostrar vacio, si queres que muestre un cero podes poner un case dentro del sum, algo asi SUM(CASE WHEN c.valor IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE c.valor END)

Comment: Juan, sabes que he echo lo que me decis pero los valores devueltos siguen siendo solo lo que tiene valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta cambiando el inner join por left join

```
SELECT e.codigo, 
      CASE
        WHEN c.valor IS NULL THEN 0
        ELSE round(sum(c.valor),2)
      END AS cupo 
FROM tbl_consumo c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_empleado e 
    on c.tbl_empleado_id=e.id 
WHERE fecha like '%2018-12%' 
GROUP BY e.codigo;
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Solamente falto cambiar el WHERE por AND para que considere el filtro de fecha correctamente...

Answer (score 2):

Al usar un **INNER JOIN**, solo obtienes los resultados que existan en ambas tablas. En tu caso lo que necesitas es usar un **LEFT JOIN** y condicionar el null resultante.

```
SELECT e.codigo, 
    ISNULL(round(sum(c.valor),2), 0) as cupo 
FROM tbl_consumo c 
LEFTJOIN tbl_empleado e 
    on c.tbl_empleado_id=e.id 
WHERE fecha like '%2018-12%' 
GROUP BY e.codigo;
```

Saludos.

Comment: Rostan, he probado con lo descrito y funciona pero si le quito el WHERE fecha... al momento de volver a poner WHERE fecha me vuelve a mostrar solamente valores con consumo... sabes que podria estar pasando?

Comment: La solucion fue cambiar el WHERE por AND...

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a todos pos sus respuestas lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT e.codigo, 
    CASE WHEN c.valor is null then 0 
    else round(sum(c.valor),2) END as cupo 
FROM tbl_empleado e 
LEFT JOIN tbl_consumo c 
on e.id=c.tbl_empleado_id 
AND c.fecha LIKE '%12-2018%' 
GROUP by e.codigo;
```

El problema inicial ha sido que colocando WHERE en lugar de AND para filtrar por fecha me daba como resultado de igual manera que con INNER JOIN, cambiandolo por AND me tomaba los valores null y los cambiaba por Cero.

Gracias!!